# Stacking matrices from a cell array on top of one another (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array, with each cell containing a 3 column matrix.

How can I stack all of these matrices together, so that there are 3 very long columns of data?

I know I could do:

```
stacked_matrix = [cellArray{1,1} ; cellArray{1,2} ; cellArray{1,N}];
```

but I want to avoid manually writing everything out because the cell array is 1x40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`cat`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) along the first dimension like this:

```
cat(1,cellArray{:})
```

---

Let's test it:

```
>> cellArray{1} = [ 1  2  3];
>> cellArray{2} = [ 4  5  6];
>> cellArray{3} = [ 7  8  9];
>> cellArray{4} = [10 11 12];

>> stacked_matrix = cat(1,cellArray{:})

stacked_matrix =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) as well:

```
out = vertcat(cellArray{:});
```

However, doing `vertcat` is essentially syntactic sugar for `cat(1,cellArray{:})` as per [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31907393/3250829).

To test:

```
cellArray{1} = [ 1  2  3];
cellArray{2} = [ 4  5  6];
cellArray{3} = [ 7  8  9];
cellArray{4} = [10 11 12];
out = vertcat(cellArray{:});
```

... and we get:

```
out =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
```

Comment: _syntactic sugar_ :-DD

Comment: @LuisMendo - lol yes :) You know what syntactic sugar is yes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar

Comment: I had an idea, but I didn't know it had a precise definition :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - I like using it when I can! :D

Comment: Maybe so will I! I like that expression